# Add Toast in public class corresponding to any event

Tags: android, android-studio

There all, i'm a newbie in android programming and i've a school task to analysis some project. So, i choose a Guitar Tuner project from github called pTune (link: [here](https://github.com/wespay/pTune)). 

I've read the code and analyze it, from what i read and see there are a needle with an arc meter to see if the input sound (guitar voice) was fit.

In that project i want to display Toast if the tuning process are fit when the dial in 90 degree. So, i've add this Toast but its not displayed..

```
    if (relativeFrequency == targetFrequency){
        Toast.makeText(PTuneActivity.this, "FIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

That code placed in updateDisplay class, i've placed it in other class but still not work as i want.

```
    public void updateDisplay(float frequency) {
    // Calculate difference between target and measured frequency,
    // given that the measured frequency can be a factor of target.
    float difference = 0;
    if (frequency > targetFrequency) {
        int divisions = (int) (frequency / targetFrequency);
        float modified = targetFrequency * (float) divisions;
        if (frequency - modified > targetFrequency / 2) {
            modified += targetFrequency;
            divisions++;
        }
        difference = (frequency - modified) / (float) divisions;
    } else {
        // If target is greater than measured, just use difference.
        difference = frequency - targetFrequency;
    }

    float relativeFrequency = targetFrequency + difference;

    // Update TextView
    if (relativeFrequency < 1000f)
        t.setText(String.format("%.1f Hz", relativeFrequency));
    else
        t.setText(String.format("%.2f kHz", relativeFrequency/1000));

    //My code
    if (relativeFrequency == targetFrequency){
        Toast.makeText(PTuneActivity.this, "FIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // Update DialView
    float value = difference / (targetFrequency / 2) * 90;
    dial.update(value);
}
```

I know this is useless in real implementation but i want to learn android programming.

Comment: I suppose both are `float` values. You sure that at one point they will be `==`?

Comment: `relativeFrequency` will always be greater than `targetFrequency + difference` ?

Comment: yea, its float but while i type = instead of == its giving an error

Answer (score 0):

You're testing equality between 2 floats, one comes from an input ? It might never be exactly equal. You should add some log and an "else" statement to see if it goes inside the "if" because the Toast may not be the real problem

Comment: hmm, so i must using "else if" right? but i dont know about log that u mean, im not good at java

Comment: Why "else if" ? What other condition you wanna test ?

Answer (score 0):

i've just try it by my self by digging and its worked for me, though its not good at all but i thinks ok, just add this line of code upper dial.update(value);

```
if (frequency >= targetFrequency) {
     Toast.makeText(PTuneActivity.this, "FIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```